# ActiveRecord.find Wrong number of arguments 2 for 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
User.find(16)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:964:in `create_binds'
```

I only passed in 1 argument, `16`. Where is this second argument coming from?

User is loading fine:

```
=> class User < ActiveRecord::Base {
                      :id => :integer,
                   :email => :string,
      :encrypted_password => :string,
    :reset_password_token => :string,
  :reset_password_sent_at => :datetime,
     :remember_created_at => :datetime,
           :sign_in_count => :integer,
      :current_sign_in_at => :datetime,
         :last_sign_in_at => :datetime,
      :current_sign_in_ip => :string,
```

etc

Comment: Try running only 'User' in console & paste result here.

Comment: Are you experimenting with ActiveRecord 4.2.0.beta or sth? `create_binds` quite recently got modified to accept two arguments. It seems that the rest of rails has been updated, but your active record library stayed st the stabe version with single argument.

Comment: http://rubyonrails.org/ shows 4.2 as the latest version. My Gemfile.lock rails (4.2.0)

Comment: @BroiSatse 2] hits_server »  User
=> class User < ActiveRecord::Base {
                      :id => :integer,
                   :email => :string,
      :encrypted_password => :string,
    :reset_password_token => :string,
  :reset_password_sent_at => :datetime,
     :remember_created_at => :datetime,
           :sign_in_count => :integer,
      :current_sign_in_at => :datetime, ..etc

Comment: Do you have any more of the stacktrace?

Comment: @quantumpotato Please edit the question rather than wedge code/config/stacktraces/etc into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use `Squeel`? Squeel is not yet compatible with Rails 4.2. In the meanwhile, you can use the Github version:

```
gem "squeel", github: "danielrhodes/squeel"
```

Note that this is not the official repository but the changes are proposed to the official one ([`PR`](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/pull/354)).